# MySQL INSERT error

Tags: php, mysql

I got this error :

```
Database problem occur, please try again later.
- Error in query: INSERT INTO main SET title ='', url='www.jerseymurah.com', kod='jerseymurah', owner='Hasbul Aqill', tag='jersey, football, world cup', since='Feb 2010', desc='ssfsfsfsfs'
- Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc='ssfsfsfsfs'' at line 1 (Error #1064)
- File: /home/yosh/domains/yosh.my/public_html/demo/admincp/tambah-save.php
```

and this is my mysql query code :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO main SET title ='".$ttile."', url='".$url."', 
kod='".$kod."', owner='".$owner."', tag='".$tag."', since='".$since."', 
desc='".$desc."'";
$db->rq($query);
```

Please help and thanks a lot!

Comment: If I am not wrong you are using UPDATE syntax to INSERT.

Comment: In the future, don't care about the PHP code if you get a SQL error: look at the SQL query first. PHP != SQL.

Comment: As an aside: Please, please, use parametrized statements, don't concatenate SQL fragments and parameters as strings, that is evil (-> SQL injection). See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection , and [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php) .

Comment: Also note that you are using a non-standard SQL syntax for your INSERT. It works with MySQL, so is not the cause of the error. Still, you might want to avoid DB-specific constructs unless there's no alternative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DESC` is a reserved word in mySQL.

You need to put that field in backticks:

```
`desc`="..."
```

maybe consider renaming the field.

[mySQL reserved words in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think DESC is a reserved word, try escaping it with backticks.

Answer (score -1):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO main(title,url,kod,owner,tag,since,description) VALUES('$title','$url','$kod','$owner','$tag','$since','$desc')");
```